# Exponential distribution and gamma prior

Tags: bayesian, exponential-distribution

I want to use Bayesian conjugate to update my prior. Let's say I model bus arrivals by Exponential distribution with `lamba=0.5`. It means on average I will wait for `2h = 1/0.5`

Prior is gamma with: `alha=1, beta=2, E[gamma] = alha/beta = 1/2`

I have observed: 'the bus arrived after 3 hours'.
Posterior: `alha += 1, beta +=3, E[gamma] = 2/5` My posterior expected waiting time will be longer `5/2=2.5`

How should I update my prior in case I have observed the next event: 'I waited for 3h and went home'. There is no information when the 'bus has arrived' but that 'it did not arrive for 3h'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prior distribution on $\lambda$ is the Gamma prior
$$\pi(\lambda)\propto\lambda^{\alpha-1}\exp\{-\beta\lambda\}\,\mathbb I_{\lambda>0}$$
The observation is the non-realisation of an event $E$. The probability that it did not occur is $\mathbb P_\lambda(E^c)$, which is also the likelihood. Hence the posterior writes as
$$\pi(\lambda|E^c)\propto\pi(\lambda)\times\mathbb P_\lambda(E^c)$$
Since the event $E^c$ means that the bus took more than three hours to come
$$\mathbb P_\lambda(E^c)=\mathbb P_\lambda(X>3)=\int_3^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,\text dx=e^{-3\lambda}$$
Therefore
$$\pi(\lambda|E^c)\propto \lambda^{\alpha-1}\exp\{-\beta\lambda\} \times \exp\{-3\lambda\}\,\mathbb I_{\lambda>0}$$

Comment: It is also nice to notice that the posterior is Gamma with parameters $\alpha,\beta+3$

Comment: @PedroSebe: yes this is what the last equation says.